# what's the difference between BRDF and Phong model?

Tags: graphics

I am wondering if Phong model is one kind of BRDF?

Is BRDF only dealing with opaque surface? If the surface is translucent, which model to use?

Answer (score 0):

There's two thing called Phong :

- a BRDF : I = Ia + Id + Is ... this is Phong model i suppose for you
- a way to interpolate illumination between vertex

so yes, what you call Phong model IS a BRDF, not a physically based one of course

and BRDF is only for opaque because it's a bidirectionnal REFLECTANCE distribution function

look at BTDF (transmission) or even BSDF (scattering)

Comment: there exist also a physically based Phong model anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Practically a general BRDF is based on microfacet theory while original Phong is not.